# Fixed navigation bar makes scrolling up in a long code sample annoying

Tags: bug, top-bar

Go to answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30274637/16673, make sure you have the top of the question hidden above the window top (as on the picture) and try to select whole code starting at the end, and gradually going up. Notice you will be selecting navbar instead of scrolling the code.

[image]

Comment: Workaround: drag the mouse past the navigation bar -- the text in it will be unselected.

Comment: I have a feeling this is tagged [bug] for a reason...

Comment: Workaround: After you start your selection of text you can use the arrow keys to select more text that is off the screen.

Comment: No repro on opera. When I move the mouse up, it scrolls up.

Comment: I've always had a slight issue with doing this and instead I've just hit edit and copied the code from the edit box rather than the actual wall.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's anything that can really be done about this. This sort of thing happens on any site with a fixed top navigation area. However, I have noticed that if you put the mouse in a place on the top bar where there isn't text, it selects fine.

But that's on Firefox; other browsers might work differently.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Sorry; brain fart.

Answer (score 1):

As a work around you can use the [SE like I like it userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/5038/se-like-i-like-it-userscript).  It will select an entire code block if you double click on it.  You also get the additional benefits amongst other things of being able to use <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in the editor like you would in an IDE.